# Is there a way to incorporate aggregate values and non-aggregate in one query without using subqueries?

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata what I want to do is create two aggregate values from doing a group by keep the aggregate values and compute a new value from the aggregate value.

I have done this simple query

```
select 
  a.*, 
  def / n as derived_dr 
from
  (select 
    obsdate
    , sum(def) as def
    , count(*) as n         
from 
    some_table
group by obsdate) as a;
```

But in SAS/SQL I can do for example

```
    select 
      a.*
      , sum(def) as def
      , count(*) as n 
      , def / n as derived_dr 
     from
         some_table as a;
```

which a lot simpler and easier to understand. But if I try the above code in Teradata it gives an error

> selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Is my original Teradata solution the best way to achieve this? I am looking for the most proper way to do this in Teradata, I think there should be a solution without using a sub-query.

Comment: Is `a.*` an alias for `some_table` which is not aliased in your `FROM` clause?

Comment: @RobPaller correct. Updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Mixing both details and aggregates in the same level are a task for [Windowed Aggregate Functions](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_015K/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.081.001.html) in Teradata/Standard SQL:

```
sum(def) over () -- global sum
sum(def) over (partition by obsdate) -- group sum, similar to GROUP BY
```